# Azure workflow can not connect to LogAnalytic

Tags: azure, workflow, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to set up a workflow to run a script on LogicApp and then send its results to LogAnalytic. I'm having problems passing the results to the LogAnalytic database. An error occurs when trying to pass data to LogAnalytic:

> Get Web Apps Hostruntime Workflow Trigger Uri - The 'ListCallbackUrl' API is not supported by triggers of type 'Recurrence'.

[image]

My workflow looks like this.

[image]

The connector is configured to connect in the LogAnalytics database - the ID and key for the connection are specified.
How to understand what is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing, this was working fine from our end. One of the workaround to make it work is to regenerate the key of your Log Analytics workspace and add the same value in your logic apps.

[image]

Below is my logic app

[image]

**RESULTS:**

- Logic app run

  [image]
- Log Analytics logs

  [image]

Comment: Thanks for help but it is still one works for me. I use standard logic app + WorkflowStandard but you use a modern (other?) logic app. It looks different in designer view. I try to use moder logic app and in this case connect to LogAnalytics is working fine. But - in this case my "create job" steps finished with failed.

Comment: I recived this error when try to use modern logic app:  <br/>"code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "{\"Message\":\"The request is invalid.\",\"ModelState\":{\"job.properties\":[\"The properties field is required.\"]}}"

Comment: Modern loggic app = Consumption logic app

Comment: @DzmitryKuzmiankou Can you add a picture of what you are doing in "create job" step